# Code end up in an endless loop. Can't see why

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

I am working on a simple function to let the user select the language.
But for some reason, I can't see my mistake and the while loop never breaks.

```py
def chooseLanguage():
    """Simple function to let the user choose what language he wants to play in"""
    if game["language"] == "en_EN":
        import res.languages.en_EN as lang

    elif game["language"] == "de_DE":
        import res.languages.de_DE as lang

    else:
        while game["language"] is None:
            print ("Hello and welcome! Please select a language.")
            print ("1. German / Deutsch")
            print ("2. English")
            langC = input ("Your choice: ")
            if inputValidator(1, langC) == 1:
                game["language"] = "de_DE"
                break
            elif inputValidator(1, langC) == 2:
                game["language"] = "en_EN"
                break

if game["language"] is None:
    chooseLanguage()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: What's the return value of `inputValidator` ?

Comment: oh boy... thank you for that hint. I was so focussed on that loop, that I havent checked the validator wich is return litteraly nothing :D

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the infinite loop was caused by inputValidator returning a value that was neither equal to 1 or 2. Thus the exit conditions of the loop were never met. And so it continues.